# How to access var parents class in a subclass

Tags: php, class, extends

How can I access the public variables from the parents class inside a subclass?

I have a couple of variables that I need to access.

For some reason i get this error 'Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in....'

```
  class mainclass{
      public $hello = 'hello';
  }
  class subclass extends mainclass{       
      public function sayhello(){
         $this->hello;// not working
      }
  }
```

Comment: Clarify what "not working" means? How exactly you're running this code?

Comment: well I get this error 'Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in....'

Comment: And how do you run this code? have you tried to google by your error message? Why haven't you?

Comment: I am still a noob so yes I have used google.

Comment: do you know what the first `o` in the `OOP` abbreviation means? PS: have you intentionally skipped my question about how you're running this code twice?

Comment: the example above is just a snippet to make things easy. My question basicly is how to access the parents vars.

Comment: you're accessing it **correctly**. The code you've provided is correct. But seems like you're not interested in learning. So, good luck then.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because "not working" is not a know php error code.

Answer (score -1):

Beacuse you dont return or not echos any value

```
 class mainclass{
      public $hello = 'hello';
  }
  class subclass extends mainclass{       
      public function sayhello(){
         echo $this->hello; // or return $this->hello

      }
  }
```

UPDATE:
Meaby you dont know how to use objects? This code work!!

```
  $class = new subclass();
  $class->sayhello();
```

Comment: `$class` is the terrible name for the *object*

Comment: it`s doesnt matter in this case!

Comment: it does matter for a newbie who doesn't know a proper terminology

Answer (score -2):

Use `parent::`

```
class mainclass{
  public $hello = 'hello';
}
class subclass extends mainclass{       
  public function sayhello(){
    echo public::hello;
  }
}
```

I would recommend to change the variable hello into private and make a getter method for this instance.